# sending email from cron with correct format

Tags: php, mysql, email, cron, mail

I am stuck when sending email in correct format from `cron` jobs executing my `php` script which fetches records from `mysql` database.

i have a `php` script which fetches records from database and renders in `<html>` format when echod in browser like

```
StartTime   EndTime     Count User  Count Apps
12:00:00    12:59:59      0             0
01:00:00    01:59:59      0             0
02:00:00    02:59:59      0             0
03:00:00    03:59:59      0             0
04:00:00    04:59:59      0             0
05:00:00    05:59:59      0             0
06:00:00    06:59:59      0             0
07:00:00    07:59:59      0             0
08:00:00    08:59:59      0             0
```

in my php script i use simple mail() and to send mail i use headers like

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";

mail("someemail@example.com",$subject,$message);
```

i set my cron job by typing like

```
crontab -e   //which opens `VI` editor
```

there i set

```
MAILTO="someemail@example.com"
10 * * * * php /var/www/html/xyz/myfile.php
```

its sending mail every hour past 10 min  but the format goes wrong.its sending mail in a format like

```
<html><head><title>Count User Info TimeWise</title></head><h2>Count     User/Application in CurrentDate</h2><body><table border="3" cellspacing="2">

 <tr><th>StartTime</th><th>EndTime</th><th>Count User</th><th>Count Apps</th>
</tr><tr><td>12:00:00</td><td>12:59:59</td><td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr>  
<td>13:00:00</td><td>13:59:59</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>14:00:00</td>
<td>14:59:59</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>15:00:00</td><td>15:59:59</td>
<td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>16:00:00</td><td>16:59:59</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>
</tr><tr><td>17:00:00</td><td>17:59:59</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr> 
<td>18:00:00</td><td>18:59:59</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>19:00:00</td>
<td>19:59:59</td><td>2</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>20:00:00</td><td>20:59:59</td>
<td>1</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>21:00:00</td><td>21:59:59</td><td>0</td><td>0</td>
</tr><tr><td>22:00:00</td><td>22:59:59</td><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr></body>  
</table></html>
```

how can i send mail in the correct format like shown when its echoed in browser?and how can i set cron to send email from 1pm to 11pm .

my `php` script

```
<?php 
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("dbname",$con);
$to="some@example.com"
$subject = 'Count User Login And Application';

//fetch between 06:00:00 to 08:30:00   09:00:00 to 10:00:00
$date=array('06:00:00','09:00:00');
$date1=array('08:30:00','10:00:00');

$msg  = '<html><head>';
$msg .='<title>Some Title</title>';
$msg .='</head>';
$msg .='<h1>Test User</h1>';
$msg .='<table border="1" cellspacing="1">';

$msg .=  "<tr>";
$msg .=  "<th>start time</th>";
$msg .=  "<th>end time</th>";
$msg .=  "<th>Count</th>";

$count=count($date);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$sql="SELECT count(*) AS test FROM table_name WHERE DATE_FORMAT(sys_time,'%H:%m:%i') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(sys_time,'$date[$i]') AND  DATE_FORMAT(sys_time,'$date1[$i]') ";
$query=mysql_query($sql);
if(!$query){
    die('could not connect'.mysql_error());}


while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

    $msg .=  "<tr>";
    $str=$row['test'];
    $subcategory = explode(',', $str);
    foreach($subcategory as $value) 
    {
        $msg .=  "<td>" . $value . "</td>";
     }
    $msg .=  "</tr>";
  } 
}
$msg .=  "</table>";      
$msg .=  "</html>";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $msg);
?>
```

please help

Comment: The `mail` command in PHP has no relation to the mail `cron` sends. `cron` emails anything that was printed to `stdout`.

Comment: To have a cron job execute every hour from 1 pm to 11 pm, start the line with `0 13-23 * * *`.

Comment: @Jos thanks.then how to send email in correct format saiarcot895 .i have also tried with removing the mail() from php script and but no success.

Comment: For this we would need to see the php script. The formatting is done by the script, certainly not by cron.

Comment: @Jos i have edited it with the php script.Thnks again

Comment: So the php script outputs HTML, which is then correctly emailed by cron. If you don't want HTML, build the $msg string without `< >` tags.

Comment: i am bit confused..though i think u mean to say that removing all the <> tags from $msg will render correctly by cron.then how could it be rendered in browser specific format with correct table row and other

Comment: So you DO want the output to be sent as HTML, only the browser doesn't render the mail as HTML. Is that correct? You don't actually send the $headers anywhere, do you? These are needed for your browser to interpret the mail body as HTML.

Comment: yes @jos i want to send email as html view with <table> <tr> <th> in order but does cron recognise those tags as i also tried removing mail() from php and also removed $msg and run my script from cron but all the tags <titles> <tr> <th> is coming as text format not html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `CentOs` to install cron type

```
yum install cronie
```

In your php script put the header section of $header above assigning $msg to intercept it as `html` content before it really assign $msg with `HTML` so it will be

```
$to="some@example.com"
$subject = 'Count User Login And Application';


$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
//try adding one more $headers with sender mail address and pass it as fourth     parameter in mail()

mail($to, $subject, $msg ,$headers);

crontab -l   //check wheather a cron tab for this user already runs
crontab -e   //to edit cron or new cron job
```

opens `VI`

```
MAILTO"some@example.com;othermail@example.com"
* 1-11 * * * php /location/of /your/file/script.php
```

press `ESC` then `capsLock ON` type `ZZ` from keyboard you are done

```
 `crontab -l`  //u can see listed cronjob
```

Comment: This is a copy/paste without giving due credits. Besides that: the 1st part is generic and we only accept Ubuntu based answer + crontab is already installed on Ubuntu. I also consider using /etc/crontab over crontab to be the wiser choice: whenever you can prevent using root you should on sudo-enabled systems.

Answer (score 1):

You should just use the PHP mail function, which your script already tries to do. Look up the syntax for the mail function and you will see that there is an additional parameter $headers. The script actually constructs these headers but does not use them. The headers are necessary to tell your email client that what follows is HTML and not plain text.
The fact that cron can send its output to an email address is not relevant and you should not rely on it. Systems administrators can use this facility as a last resort, to be certain that any unexpected output from a cron job is brought to their attention. It was never meant as a full-fledged mailing facility such as offered by PHP.